# How to create shortcut to "this.someMethod = this.someMethod.bind(this)" with IntelliJ live templates?

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create some autocomplete shortcut with IntelliJ live templates, 
I have to write a "Template Text" expression so intellj will support the following action:
I will write: `this.someMethod().bind` then I'll press <kbd>Tab</kbd>

The result I expect:

```
this.someMethod = this.someMethod.bind(this); <- cursor will jump here
```

I've tried some expression following this guide, but it's didn't succeed - 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/template-variables.html

Tried things like:

```
$item$ = $item$.bind(this);$end$
```

[image: Live Templates In IntelliJ Settings]

Comment: You can try using the postfix completion: https://i.gyazo.com/d1ea877980f51a6dce064057528016d8.png

Comment: Thank you @Oksana it is an excellent alternative, works!